# Right way to replace string with php ming

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, libming

I'm doing a Chronometer with PHPMing, the chronometer value changes 20 times per second and I'm getting some errors on long files (around 7 mins, 8000 text changes)

I wonder if there is a way to just replace the text instead of remove and add it again, that it's how I'm doing

```
$counter = Array('0.00.000', '0.00.050', '0.00.100'....
    foreach($counter as $ky => $value) {
      $text = $value;
      $is = $m -> remove($is);
      $t = new SWFText();
      $t -> setFont($f);
      $t -> addString($text);
      $is = $m -> add($t);
      $is -> moveTo(70, 570);
      $m - > nextframe();
    }
```

Comment: Why you added `actionscript-3` and `swf` tag?

Comment: PHP ming generates swf files and also support AS3 input